# Why is the collection of decision problems closed under set operations?

Tags: turing-machines, decision-problem, closure-properties

Most of the proofs of such properties that I see involve informally using algorithms or invoking Turing machines as needed. But it's not clear to me how are we using set operations on instances of decision problems? Moreover, it is not intuitively clear to me how we can use different instances of decision problems for ex. I have seen some problem $P$ whose instance is say an undirected graph and a problem $Q$ has strings in $\Sigma^*$ as instance how can we use set operations such as complement or intersection here? Is there some inhuman level of abstraction at play here?

Comment: Are you familiar with encoding, like [Gödel encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del_numbering)?

Comment: Somewhat familiar yes.